# Error: no permission to append row

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following google script. Trying to append the results to row and I get this error

> "You do not have permission to call appendRow (line 11)."

```
function webs() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    var url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/mailbox/mailMessages/17685?include_body=1";
    var token  = "&api_token=token"

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+token);
    var dataSet = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    sheet.appendRow([dataSet.data.body]);
}
```

Anyway around this? if I can't append in google sheets, is there anyway to add results to a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use an [**Installable Trigger**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead of using a [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) which have [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) on what they can do.

See how to install it [manually here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually):

1. From the script editor, choose Edit > Current project's triggers.
2. Click the link that says: No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
3. Under Run, select the name of function you want to trigger.
4. Under Events, select either Time-driven or the Google App that the script is bound to (for example, From spreadsheet).
5. Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create (for example, an Hour timer that runs Every hour or an On open trigger).
6. Optionally, click Notifications to configure how and when you will be contacted by email if your triggered function fails.
   Click Save.

---

**Edit:** I could also be [restrictions on custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values):

> A custom function **cannot affect cells other than those it returns a value to**. In other words, a custom function cannot edit arbitrary cells, only the cells it is called from and their adjacent cells. To edit arbitrary cells, use a custom menu to run a function instead.

---

**Edit:** Other times you just need to authorize it first. Try going to Run > Run Function > then choose any function to run. Apps Script will pop-up with a authorization window for all the new scopes you are using.